# How to cache a component once its route is activated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, caching, angular-ui-router

I have 3 components.
1 parent and 2 child component with router outlet so child component is active whenever its route is called (sharing data using service).

I have complex view for both of this child components.

when i switch between this two routes it takes too much time to render view. ( i have used some bootstrap UI, ngbootstrap, and some more libraries)

my data is not changing between this 2 child components only view part changes which takes time.

so i was wondering is there any way to cache this component once they are called ? to improve performance ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, make sure to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, so others can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question, I've never used it, but you can achieve that with [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy). You didn't provide your specific example, but generally you need to use methods:

- **shouldAttach** - **returns true/false** to determine whether **retrieve** method will be called to fetch the component instead of creating it from scratch.
- **retrieve** - **returns RouteHandle or null** if it's called - it can return **saved (cached)** component as a **DetachedRouteHandle**.
- **shouldDetach** - **returns true/false** to determine whether **store** method will be called.
- **store** - **returns nothing** but accepts **detachedTree** that you can **save (cache)** to store your component state and further return it from **retrieve** method.

It sounds complex, but it's easier to do that, than replacing **router-outlet** to some custom thing. [Here is](https://itnext.io/cache-components-with-angular-routereusestrategy-3e4c8b174d5f) the guy describes that really well and provides an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: will it store all subscription i have in child components ?

Comment: As i understood it won't call **ngOnDestroy()**, so yes it will store all subscriptions, but you can double check that putting `console.log` in **ngOnDestroy** to check whether it's being called.

Comment: can you provide some more info on how to destory child component when its parent is destroyed ?